# using a shared library : custom myfopen(), myfrwrite()

Tags: c, bash, shared-libraries, fopen, fwrite

Hello I have created a shared library named `logger.so`. This library is my custom `fopen()` and `fwrite()`. It collects some data and produce a file with these data.

Now I am writing a bash script and I want to use this library as well. Producing a txt file I would be able to see the extra file that produce my custom `fopen()`. So when I use the command `fopen()` in a c file this extra file is produced.

My Question is which commands are using `fopen()` and `fwrite()` functions in bash?

I have already preloaded my shared library but It doesn't work. Maybe these commands don't use `fopen()`,`fwrite()`

```
export LD_PRELOAD=./logger.so 

read -p 'Enter the number of your files to create: [ENTER]: ' file_number


for ((i=1; i<=file_number; i++))
do
     echo file_"$i" > "file_${i}"
done
```

Comment: Why don't you just check the source code and see for yourself?

Comment: could you please suggest me where exactly Can I do my research?

Comment: Here you go https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may require some trial and error. I see two ways to do this. One is to run potential commands that deal with files in `bash` and see if when traced they call `fopen`:

```
strace bash -c "read a < /dev/null"`
```

or

```
strace bash -c "read a < /dev/null"` 2&>1 | fgrep fopen
```

This shows that that `read` uses `open`, not `fopen`.

Another way is to `grep` through the source code of bash as @oguz suggested. When I did this I found several places where `fopen` is called, but I did not investigate further:

```
curl https://mirrors.tripadvisor.com/gnu/bash/bash-5.1-rc3.tar.gz|tar -z -x --to-stdout --wildcards \*.c | fgrep fopen
```

You'll want to unarchive the whole package and search through the .c files one by one, e.g.:

```
curl https://mirrors.tripadvisor.com/gnu/bash/bash-5.1-rc3.tar.gz|tar -z -v -x --wildcards \*.c
```

You can also FTP the file or save it via a browser and do the `tar` standalone if you don't have `curl` (`wget` will also work).

Hopefully you can trace the relevant commands but it might not be easy.

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily every program uses C standard library stdio functions `fopen` and `fwrite`.

But every program uses `open` and `write` syscalls to open and write files, which you can interpose / monkey-patch.

Modern programs that use `io_uring` require a different method of interposing.